# SQL Server 2000 Full Text Index running on Windows Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, full-text-indexing

I have SQL Server 2000 SP4 running on Windows Server 2008, and I'm trying create a full text  catalog that includes full text indexes on a few tables. The catalog has an Item Count of 53676, but a unique key count of only 8.

On another database (a Windows Server 2003 machine) with the exact same data, i have the exact same Full Text catalog set up and the unique key count is 75312.

What could cause the unique key count to be so low?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the minimum and maximum indexed word lengths are the same on both machines?